# How to Whois in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to get the location of people logging into my website and I think it is called Whois. 
So how would I go about locating people in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get their IP using:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

and get a free database to convert ip to location :)

**[Here is one resource.](http://www.tamos.com/products/ip-location-database/)**

Also, you can find a host of free scrips out there.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to consider users behind proxies, as `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` may return the wrong IP address in that context. Check `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` first to guard against this.

```
function getIpAddress() {
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
    return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
  }
  return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this also I'll need this +1 for getting involved intensly

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to do whois. you need to grab their IP address and map it to a location. here's how you get the IP address

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Google provides free IP Address to location services. whenever you use google jsapi script google automatically populates the google.loader.ClientLocation which has all the juicy details you need.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of examples

http://www.phpwhois.com/

http://www.nott.org/blog/php-whois-script.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes shell_exec is the most elegant solution. Use at your own risk of course.

```
<?php

$domain = "stackoverflow.com";

echo shell_exec("host -t a $domain");
echo shell_exec("host -t mx $domain");
echo shell_exec("host -t ns $domain");
echo shell_exec("host -t txt $domain");
echo shell_exec("host -t cname $domain");
echo shell_exec("host -t soa $domain");
```